# Generate highly unique string for e-commerce

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, unique-key

For generating unique Order Numbers in my e-commerce application, i am contemplating two methods with the same worry.

**First:**

1. Generating a unique string through this algo

   ```
   $orderNumber = "AU".substr(substr(mt_rand(),2,5) . substr(uniqid(),5,4). substr(time(),6,4),0,18);
   ```
2. then, checking if it exists in the orders table, if not go ahead and use otherwise generate another one.

**Second:**

1. creating a table with id auto incrementing from 2147483647
2. querying the table's max value, increasing by one and going ahead with rest of stuff

**Problem at hand** : how can i ensure that in both the approaches the table is not called at the very same second which will result in duplicate order numbers? Will `mysql` lock tables on read operation if another request comes in at the very same moment?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

***First***:

1. You need explicit locks on the table. It is because the primary key
   code generation is random and not sure if it was already there in
   the table.

***Second***:

1. Auto incremented primary key with `unsigned bigint` can be a better
   choice if you are really expecting a huge amount of records in short time.
2. No need to manual check if it was already present in the table.
3. Explicit locks are not required and the engine will take care to
   maintain the uniqueness on the generated value on each request.